# Trying to constrain to the upperbound of the Number class without implementing Comparable for the entire class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, static, comparable

I'm trying to make it so that my class is only constrained to the upperbound Number. However, when I try to do a toString() method to get the smallest and largest values, I get the following message:

> The method largest(`ArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>>`) in the type MyList is not applicable for the arguments (`ArrayList<T extends Number>`)

```
package p07;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList<T extends Number>
{
    private ArrayList<T> l;

    public MyList(ArrayList<T> l)
    {
        this.l=l;
    }
    public void add(T x)
    {
        l.add(x);
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<T> > T smallest(ArrayList<T> l)
    {
        T lowest=l.get(0);
        for(T index:l)
        {
            if(index.compareTo(lowest)<0)
            {
                lowest=index;
            }

        }
        return lowest;

    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<T> > T largest(ArrayList<T> l)
    {
        T largest=l.get(0);
        for(T index:l)
        {
            if(index.compareTo(largest)>0)
            {
                largest=index;
            }

        }
        return largest;

    }
    public final String toString()
    {
        String str;
        str="\nThe list is: ";
        str+="\n"+l.toString();
        str+="\nThe largest value is "+MyList.largest(l);
        str+="\nThe smallest value is "+MyList.smallest(l);
        return str;
    }

}
```

Is there any way for me to keep my class constrained to the upper bound of the Numbers class without having to implement the Comparable interface for the entire class? I have a feeling the error is occurring because my methods are static, but I'm not sure. I only want to use Comparable for

```
smallest()
```

and

```
largest()
```

Comment: not same problem as the "duplicate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work --

```
public class MyList< T extends Number & Comparable<? super T> >

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> > T smallest(ArrayList<T> l)

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> > T largest(ArrayList<T> l)
```

You may also remove all the `? super` part; it should work fine without wildcards.

Comment: yes; methods `smallest/largest` need to be fixed too.

Comment: I  should clarify that I only want the users to be able to make Number arrays, and not String arrays. When I tried entering this in, my program still allowed me to make string arrays for MyList

Comment: `MyList<String>` wont' compile.

Comment: I just double checked my code. Sorry about that. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense for your `toString` method to depend on `T` having a bound that your class does not enforce.

Something like that could be done with a static method.

```
static <T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> String getString(MyList<T> list) {
    ....
}
```